# why inputstream can not recieve a message before the outputstream close in TCP

Tags: java, tcp, io

I use code like this in my client

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(mssage);
    out.flush();

    while(true){

    }
```

with this code in my server

`DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream( c1.getInputStream()) ;
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());`

it works.
However, if I use this following code in my client

```
    OutputStream out=client.getOutputStream();

    out.write(mssage.getBytes());


    out.flush();

    while(true){

    }
```

and this code in my server

```
    InputStream in= c1.getInputStream();
        byte [] b=new byte [32];

        while((in.read(b))!=-1){

            toprint+=new String (b);

        }
        System.out.print(toprint);
```

the server can not receive the massage until i close the client or close the outputstream,and there will a connection reset error.
 What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is reading its input stream until end of stream before it prints anything, and end of stream on a socket doesn't occur until the peer closes the socket or shuts it down for output.

The other problem is that your read loop isn't correct, as it ignores the read count.

Try this:

```
int count;
while ((count = in.read(b)) != -1){

    toprint+=new String (b, 0, count);
    System.out.write(b, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: but why it does not to close the socket or  the DataOuputStream, when I use DataOuputStream to send in my client and use DataInputStream to read in my server.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of that, but it has nothing to do with `DataInput/OutputStream`. It is the way all socket streams behave. You're reading to end of stream, and end of stream means the peer has disconnected. Try printing the characters as you receive them.